# virtual memory on windows

Tags: ram, virtual-memory, temporary-files, swapfile

I am developing a program which use huge ram size. Unfortunately there is no way to decrease it. In linux when ram is low I can generate a swap file and mount it to system that solve my problem but in windows how can I do that or is there any api(c/c++) that can use a temp file like a ram?

Comment: don't understand your question. Are you looking for memory-mapped file WINAPI?

Comment: I want to use a temporary file in disk like a ram and these should effect physical ram size so much

Comment: winapi "memory-mapped file"?https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx

Comment: when I map a file to pointer for example 2.5 gb is it also use ram? or is it using directly file?